# when open the android application, happen "Didn't find class "com.example.hello.hello" on path "

Tags: android, manifest

I have this error "Didn't find class "com.example.hello.hello" on path".

hello/AndroidManifest.xml is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity 
          android:name="hello"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[link is picture, show the code and error window](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgo81ctxbhm1hra/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%96%202014-04-06%2020.43.48.png)

I think the problem is

```
android:name="hello"
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: ok, I follow @dcharms method to create a src relation java file, the hello empty window is show, thank every body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the full package name to your activity there. Example:

```
android:name="com.example.hello.MainActivity"
```

**EDIT**

Now that we know you have an empty src folder, you need to add a package that matches your Android package name in your manifest. Right click on your `src` folder and New -> Package. Name it "com.example.hello". Then right click on this new package and choose New -> Class.
Name this MainActivity.

You will probably want to read some tutorials on what you need to do to create the code for an activity.

Comment: error, the same result

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpxuht4psgf56nc/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%96%202014-04-06%2021.04.12.png

Comment: please post your whole stack trace and java class

Comment: This was just an example. You need to replace MainActivity with your activity name. It also looks like your `src` folder is empty, which would mean you do not have any code...

Comment: + 1 for spotting that src folder is **empty** ! Obviously it cannot find anything...

Comment: In the src->com.example.hello->MainActivity.java

I type as follow code 

    package com.example.hello;

public class MainActivity {

}

and change android:name="com.example.hello"> replace      android:name="com.example.hello.MainActivity"> of the AndroidManifest.xml , the result is "hello has stopped"

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of your activity class, it's probably Hello (Uppercase) or MainActivity (if you followed the wizard template), and as dcharms pointed out prepend the package name to it, "com.example.hello.Hello" or "com.example.hello.MainActivity"

Comment: Please tell me the path of "activity class" ?

Comment: Please refer to this answer, your problem has already been detected:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22894345/2452039

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your activity name in manifest and the class you crated. 
your activity should be defined

```
    android:name="com.example.hello.hello"
```

this way where hello is the activity you created in your hello package.

Go through your naming conventions once again and also try to post the whole stack-trace

Comment: the same error, as picture link https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpxuht4psgf56nc/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%96%202014-04-06%2021.04.12.png

Comment: @Setu if you are not going to expand on existing answers, could you at least up-vote the original answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshots, your `src` folder is empty, which means you are minimum missing your "hello" activity.

Please implement if first, or read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html). You could choose **Blank Activity** when creating android project with eclipse to have it generated.

When you specify the name of activity, mind the preceding dot :

```
<activity 
          android:name=".MyFirstActivity"
```

otherwise, you would need full class name, such as "com.example.hello.MyFirstActivity"

Comment: I just choose Blank Activity, like you.

Comment: specify a name for that activity, like "MyFirstActivity" and put the same name in your manifest : `<activity 
          android:name=".MyFirstActivity"`